# cocos2d-x 3.0rc0 : build win32 with MinGW

Tags: windows-xp, mingw, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm writing a program with cocos2d-x 3.0rc0. Since I'm on windows xp, I can't build win32 (with VS2012/2013). However, I can use MinGW. Can I use MinGW to build cocos2d-x program? If so, How can I do?

Comment: why you need MinGW? You can build cocos2dx projects without any CYGWIN or Python etc on Windows. Follow http://patidarvikas.blogspot.in/ link Just skip step 3 and 4, rather create a virtual folder for assets and link it to resources folder.

Comment: @Cocos2dx Um.. Does it work in 3.0rc0?

Comment: It has nothing to do with any version. Latest version of NDK allows you to build any NDK project without any Linux environment.